# Find exceptional parameters

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have been given an excel document with many rows full of numbers, some rows are marked.

Each row represents a case in the clinic, each column represents a research test parameter.

I need to find, what's so special about these marks that make them marked, and it has to be in a unified pattern, so I can create an algorithm to find the same exceptions in the Excel file.

I'll be using C# to write the program, but I'm sure the question is about what to look into rather than how to actually write the code.

I'm brand new to this website, I'm a programmer, not a math genius, so please be patient. I'll check for comments and respond as soon as possible.

Comment: What percentage of rows are marked? How many columns has your excel document? The C-# constraint: a distinction needs to be made between building a decision rule and evaluating a new instance using an existing decision rule. You could use a more elaborate existing tool (such as those implemented in R) to build an optimal decision rule and then implement only the resulting decision rule in C# to classify new instances.

Comment: @user603 I don't know what percentage, but do I have to know? Since I'm new to stats, can you please try to explain? Columns like 8-9 params. I added a couple of lines to my answer.

Comment: @user603, it's not that I mind using anything else, it's just that C# is my home language. What's R? Sorry if this question is too noob

Comment: I'm checking it out now.

Comment: Your question is good. I was suggesting some additional quantitative infos. Maybe I haven't understood your question but from the description, I would think it should be possible to know what percentage of all rows are marked.

Comment: Is R something that you learn in 10 minutes?

Comment: Yes, probably: [R](http://cran.r-project.org/). It's a langua franca of sort in data analysis. But my point was not to advertise it: merely to point out that there are some quiet developed open source data analysis infrastructures that you could take advantage of which would IMO make it simpler than implementing all the tools from scratch.

Comment: @user603 I definitely agree. BTW, is there a Windows build of R too?

Comment: yes. Your problem is classification (you have to imagine an additional column taking values 1 for those marked rows and 0 otherwise). This is a very heavily studied area of statistics and there are many specialists here. I'm sure your question will get better answers soon. In the mean time you could try your hand on [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Classification/kNN) simple self contained example of classification task using (one of?) the simplest classifier around: the KNN.

Comment: Also, the excellent book ['Elements of statistical learning'](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)  discusses these methods in great depth.

Comment: I agree with @user603 that it sounds like what's essentially a classification problem. Among useful things to consider would be logistic regression (the binary variable being 'marked/not-marked'). I also think that the recommendation of Hastie et al as a reference is a good one. (No, you can't learn R in ten minutes, but you can maybe learn enough to fit a very basic model and maybe do a plot in that time.)